# How in IDA can save memory dump with command or script?

Tags: python, debugging, reverse-engineering, ida

1. IDA, Hex-View [image: here picture]
2. I select with mouse zone of bytes from StartAddress to EndAddress
3. Right Click -> Save to File
4. Got memory dump.

How do the same with command?Like:
SaveDump(StartAddress , EndAddress)
SaveDump(0x00001000 , 0x00002000)

Comment: No hackers here?  Its so bad.

Answer (score 10):

yes that works, but it's very slow writing a single byte at a time. 
try this for instant dumping:

```
auto fname      = "C:\\dump_mem.bin";
auto address    = 0x0400000;
auto size       = 0x0300000;
auto file= fopen(fname, "wb");

savefile(file, 0, address, size);
fclose(file);
```

Answer (score 6):

Using the IDA Python API, you can save off a region of memory using the following script, which will prompt you to specify where the resulting file should be saved:

```python
filename = AskFile(1, "*.bin", "Output file name")
address = 0x009DD5B8
size = 0x37a0
dbgr = False
with open(filename, "wb") as out:
    data = GetManyBytes(address, size, use_dbg=dbgr)
    out.write(data)
```

If you want to save off the bytes corresponding to a memory region that you've highlighted in the graphical interface, you can use the following in the script above:

```python
address = idc.read_selection_start()
if address == idc.BADADDR:
    raise Exception("No memory region selected")
size = idc.read_selection_end() - address
```

Set `dbgr` to `True` if the script is run during a debugger session.

Answer (score 4):

Press Shift + F2 in IDA, and paste this script:

```
auto file, fname, i, address, size, x;
address = 0x0159ADB0;
size = 0xEA90;
fname = "C:\\dump_mem.bin";
file = fopen(fname, "wb");
for (i=0; i<size; i++, address++)
{
 x = DbgByte(address);
 fputc(x, file);
}
fclose(file);
```

Run script , u ll get dump_mem.bin  file from  0x0159ADB0 and size 0xEA90

Comment: DbgByte doesn't work if the executable is not launched for debugging?